# C++ Read Memory Address / Pointer & Offset

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, offset

So, I have injected a DLL into a process (a game) so that I can read from the process memory.

I want to get the current game time, and I've found the static base address & offset of it using Cheat Engine :

"game.exe"+0158069C

Offset : 14

And this is the code I've tried to get the float value (current game timer) :

```
//Offsets
#define BASETIME 0x158069C
#define OFFSET 0x14

void CurrentTime() {

    float *time;
    DWORD *BaseAddress = (DWORD*)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    DWORD *BaseTimeAddress = (DWORD*)(BaseAddress + BASETIME);
    time = (float*)(BaseTimeAddress + OFFSET);

    if (BaseTimeAddress && time) //Check the addresses, not values.
    {
        std::cout << "Base Address : " << BaseAddress << endl; // Correct
        std::cout << "Base Time Address &: " << &BaseTimeAddress << endl; // Not correct
        std::cout << "Base Time Address : " << BaseTimeAddress << endl; // Not correct
        std::cout << "Time Value : " << *time << endl; // Not correct
    }
}
```

The cout of the Base Address is correct (I can check it with Cheat Engine), but after that everything is wrong, can you help me ? I'm stuck with this and I've tried many things ... :/

Thank you in advance,

Comment: It doesn't help printing the address of a pointer. `&BaseTimeAddress`.  All that does is give you the location in memory where the pointer is stored.  So you can throw out the second `cout` line.  The last two, well, what did you expect to see?

Comment: Also, is your offset value based on the number of bytes (not DWORD's)?  If so, you are incrementing by `OFFSET * sizeof(DWORD)` bytes, and not by `OFFSET` bytes.

Comment: I print those things to see the result I've got so I can understand what happens.

If I use the dev calculator in hexadecimal and then let's pretend my BaseAddress is 12E0000 and then i add 158069C to it, I got this result : 286069C

If I add this address and my offset in Cheat Engine like so :
http://gyazo.com/18a9a846131cdd5f1e45ae3581121074

I got the same result as this, logic :
http://gyazo.com/dc01935dffa3a6623e9cfd11d4ec6364

I want to do the same thing so that I can get the float value (the current game timer) 

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: So let's make this simple and use easy numbers:  If the start address is 200, if you add 5 byte to it, do you expect to get to address 205?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to increment your pointer by `OFFSET` and `BASETIME` bytes.  If so, your code is not incrementing on a byte basis.  Instead it is incrementing by `sizeof(DWORD) * OFFSET` bytes.

The reason is that the base pointer type is `DWORD*`, and incrementing pointers of this type by `n` will get you to `n * sizeof(DWORD)` away from the start.  This will not do the job.

The easiest solution is to cast to a `char *` when doing the pointer arithmetic, so that the increment is going by `sizeof(char)`, not `sizeof(DWORD)`:

```
 DWORD *BaseTimeAddress = (DWORD*)((char *)BaseAddress + BASETIME);
 time = (float*)((char *)BaseTimeAddress + OFFSET);
```

Now, whether where you end up is the data you want, that is something I can't answer.  However if your goal was to increment on a byte basis, then you should make the corrections as shown above.

Comment: Ok, I think I've understand! I'm a beginner and maybe I'm starting with something too big, but at least I enjoy it so maybe I will remember it 

I will try that, thanks a lot anyway !

Answer (score 3):

Thank you PaulMcKenzie I got it,

So for those who struggle like me, this is the final code who actually work :

```
//Offsets
#define BASETIME 0x0158069C
#define OFFSET 0x14

void CurrentTime() {

    DWORD* BaseAddress = (DWORD*)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    DWORD* address = (DWORD*)((char*)BaseAddress + BASETIME);
    address = (DWORD*)((char*)*address + OFFSET);
    float currentTime = *(float*)address;

    if (address && currentTime)
    {
        std::cout << endl <<"----------------" << endl;
        std::cout << "Base Address : " << BaseAddress << endl;
        std::cout << "----------------" << endl;
        std::cout << "Time Address : " << address << endl;
        std::cout << "----------------" << endl;
        std::cout << "Time Value : " << currentTime << endl;
        std::cout << "----------------" << endl << endl << "#> ";
    }

}
```